# Not able to fetch registered project details, google developer console

Tags: google-signin, google-developers-console, google-console-developer, google-developer-tools

I was going integrate google login in application.
As i have login into https://console.developers.google.com/ but not able to get my project (which i have created) data for client ID and client secret Key, or other details. I don't know what is happening.

**Error**, when i search my project name and clicked i get this 
[image]

**Error** when, all registered projects are fetched.
[image: even all registered projects are not fetched]

Answer (score 0):

As I was on Google Chrome. It was not working, but when i shifted to incognito mode. It works well. Please do hard refresh for well response.